# What is orderInCategory in ActionBar menu item & why it is use for..?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

Im working on action menu item and its over flow item this is my `main_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:title="@string/start_new_project"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_dts_overflow"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow_round"
    android:orderInCategory="11111" 
    android:title="Service"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_newProject"
            android:icon="@drawable/newproject"
            android:title="@string/start_new_project"
            app:showAsAction="never" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_help"
            android:icon="@drawable/help"
            android:title="Service Tasks"
            app:showAsAction="never" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_signOut"
            android:icon="@drawable/signout"
            android:title="@string/menusignout"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

    </menu>
</item>
```

I tried to construct a search item and a overflow item which you can see in the above code. I'm new to Action bar menu items so i tried to Google it and was able to make it work as I need.

In this I have to know one more thing.

**1.** What is `orderInCategory` with some numbers and what for it is used..?

Comment: To specify the order in which menu items are displayed in the overflow-menu or actionbar

Comment: what does the number represent for..?

Comment: If you use the android:orderInCategory property, all items in the menu need to have that property. Otherwise, any items without the property will be pulled to the top/front.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`android:orderInCategory` is an integer attribute that dictates the order in which the menu items will appear within the menu when it is displayed.

```
<menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_first"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/string_one"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_second"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/string_two"/>

</menu>
```

- > Menu items in `ToolBar` are arranged from `left` to `right` (or
  >   `start` to `end` in RTL mode) in the ascending order (i.e. 1,2,3 `->`
  >   left to right).

  [image: horizontal menu items]
- > Menu Items in `Overflow menu` are arranged from `top` to `bottom` in
  >   the ascending order (i.e. 1,2,3 `->` top to bottom).

  [image: vertical overflow menu]

Comment: Notice it could be start to end to support right to left

Answer (score 36):

`android:orderInCategory` is actually useful in **two ways**.

**1.** For menu items in `ActionBar`.
       Items will appear from left to right in ActionBar depending on the ascending order.

**2.** For menu items in `overflow` menu.
       Overflow menu items will be displayed from top to bottom depending upon the ascending order you have specified.

Comment: Also useful for use when fragment and activities have menu items.  In my case I wanted the activity items to show under the fragment items and giving the activity items all an orderInCagegory accomplished this.

Comment: As far as I see, the order in ActionBar and overflow menu can be achieved simply by moving the elements into the appropriate order in the xml file. This attribute is only useful if you have menu items contributed from both activity and fragment(s) and you want more fine grained control over the order in which they appear together.

Answer (score 7):

`android:orderInCategory` **Higher value, lower priority.**

I have a Activity and a Fragment in it, both of them have option menu, and the item numbers are 1 and 3.

If I set `android:orderInCategory=0`, the activity menu are above the fragment menu, same effect before I set the value.

But if I set `android:orderInCategory=1`,the activity menu are below the fragment menu, and that is what I want.(I also test `android:orderInCategory=5`  tested too, still the same effect.)