# Add items to menu group programatically in navigation view

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, menuitem

I am trying to add menu items to menu group pragmatically but I found no way to do that. I am using Navigation View and added below mentioned menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_lang_currency"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:title="" />

    <group android:id="@+id/nav_refer" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_setting"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
        android:title="" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:title="" />

</menu>
```

Everything looks good as mentioned.

I just want to add multiple menu items in `nav_refer` group at run-time as per business requirement but I found no way to do that.

I searched solution on SO but found no way to do that.

Kindly suggest me how to add multiple menu items in group at run-time.

Answer (score 11):

To add menu to a particular group, call this method [Menu.add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

```
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    menu.add(R.id.nav_refer, 123, Menu.NONE, "Title1");
    menu.add(R.id.nav_refer, 124, Menu.NONE, "Title2");
    menu.add(R.id.nav_refer, 125, Menu.NONE, "Title3");
```

**Important** : Initially if you have **empty group** then newly added items will appear in bottom, to solve this you need to mention orders for groups. add a attribute for all your groups `android:orderInCategory="101"`

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue but the above solution does not work for me. Where does 101 come from?

Comment: @AnkitBatra please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715765/what-is-orderincategory-in-actionbar-menu-item-why-it-is-use-for for `android:orderInCategory` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, @Bharatesh. I have solved the issue I was facing.

Comment: well in that case items will be in the top

Comment: e.g. you have 3 and you need to add items to the second group, then set 100 order for first group, 101 for second, 102 for thirst and then add items to second group using `menu.add(R.id.nav_refer, ITEM_ID, 101, ITEM_TITLE);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navView);
Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("sub menu");
subMenu.add("item 1");
subMenu.add("item 2");
subMenu.add("item 3");
```

Answer (score -2):

create res --> menu file new layout

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="حساب کاربری">
            <menu>
                <group android:title="حساب کاربری">
                    <item android:title="ورود" />
                    <item android:title="ثبت نام" />
                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="سایت">
            <menu>
                <group android:title="حساب کاربری">
                    <item android:title="ورود" />
                    <item android:title="ثبت نام" />
                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

set NavigationView to app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"

i hope help you